# How do I locate an erroneous value for a parameter in a web service call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

When I make an ajax call to a WebMethod, get the server error:
The value

> The value
> "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
> is not of type "KBO.StoreLib.RootNode" and cannot be used in this
> generic collection. Parameter name: value

The call is simple ...

```
 static AllocationQuery(url: string, method: string, AjaxBookGenieParams:AjaxBookGenieParams, allowWindowClose : boolean) {
    if (this.kboAjaxIsActive) return; // prevent double clicks - racing
    this.kboAjaxIsActive = true;
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify({AjaxBookGenieParams: AjaxBookGenieParams,}) ;
    let myUrl = url + method;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: jsonString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: allowWindowClose, //blocks window close
        success: this.Allocatiom_Success,
        error: this.Allocation_Error
    });
}
```

The web method is also simple...

```
 [WebMethod]
public AjaxBookGenieParams StartNewAllocation(AjaxBookGenieParams AjaxBookGenieParams)
{
    StaticState.SetIsWebApi();
    AjaxBookGenieParams = BookGenieHandler.BuildAllocationData(AjaxBookGenieParams);
    AjaxBookGenieParams = BookGenieHandler.AllocateNextTitle(AjaxBookGenieParams);
    return AjaxBookGenieParams;
}
```

The associated ajaxcall.json is ...

```
{"AjaxBookGenieParams":{"AgeCandidates":[],"Book":{"ISBN":"","ProductId":0,"ImageUrl":"","Title":"","Price":0,"Quantity":0,"AgeId":0},"AllocatedBooks":[],"BookGenieParams":{"AllocatedQuantity":0,"AllocatedSubTotal":0,"AllocatedTitles":0,"AllocationBudget":200,"BooksPerTitle":5,"CustomerGuid":"","CustomerId":0,"DefaultBooksPerTitle":5,"MinimumBudget":200,"MoveToCartSubTotal":0,"MoveToCartCount":0,"ReDisplayBreak":10,"SelectedCategories":[],"UserBooksPerTitle":0},"Data":"","ProductFilterParams":{"RootNodes":[{"Id":50,"Name":"Ages","GroupType":"ages","NodeCategories":[{"Id":38,"Name":"Ages 0 to 2","Count":54,"Selected":"off","Description":"","GroupCats":[]},{"Id":34,"Name":"Ages 3 to 5","Count":536,"Selected":"off","Description":"","GroupCats":[]},{"Id":35,"Name":"Ages 6 to 8","Count":471,"Selected":"off","Description":"","GroupCats":[]},{"Id":37,"Name":"Ages 9 to 12","Count":1126,"Selected":"off","Description":"","GroupCats":[]},{"Id":36,"Name":"Young Adult","Count":803,"Selected":"off","Description":"","GroupCats":[]}],"Description":"Books By Age","ToolTip":"","Selected":"off","__expanded__":false}],"FilterGuid":"","AgeRange":{"Min":1,"Max":18,"From":3,"FromInit":3,"To":12,"ToInit":12},"SelectedAges":[],"FilterCategories":{},"ResetFilter":"false"},"Request":"StartAllocationToCart"}}
```

Since the initial load json is ...

```
{
"AgeCandidates": [
    {
        "AllocationCandidates": [],
        "AgeId": 0
    }
],
"Book": {
    "AgeId": 0,
    "ImageURL": "",
    "ISBN": "",
    "Price": 0.0,
    "ProductId": 0,
    "Quantity": 0,
    "Title": ""
},
"AllocatedBooks": [],
"BookGenieParams": {
    "AllocatedQuantity": 0,
    "AllocatedSubTotal": 0.0,
    "AllocatedTitles": 0,
    "AllocationBudget": 200,
    "BooksPerTitle": 3,
    "CustomerGuid": "",
    "CustomerId": 0,
    "DefaultBooksPerTitle": 5,
    "MinimumBudget": 200,
    "MoveToCartSubTotal": 0.0,
    "MoveToCartCount": 0,
    "ReDisplayBreak": 10,
    "SelectedCategories": [],
    "UserBooksPerTitle": 0
},
"Data": "",
"ProductFilterParams": {
    "RootNodes": [
        {
            "Id": 50,
            "Name": "Ages",
            "GroupType": "ages",
            "NodeCategories": [
                {
                    "Id": 38,
                    "Name": "Ages 0 to 2",
                    "Count": 54,
                    "Selected": "off",
                    "Description": "",
                    "GroupCats": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": 34,
                    "Name": "Ages 3 to 5",
                    "Count": 536,
                    "Selected": "off",
                    "Description": "",
                    "GroupCats": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": 35,
                    "Name": "Ages 6 to 8",
                    "Count": 471,
                    "Selected": "off",
                    "Description": "",
                    "GroupCats": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": 37,
                    "Name": "Ages 9 to 12",
                    "Count": 1126,
                    "Selected": "off",
                    "Description": "",
                    "GroupCats": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": 36,
                    "Name": "Young Adult",
                    "Count": 803,
                    "Selected": "off",
                    "Description": "",
                    "GroupCats": []
                }
            ],
            "Description": "Books By Age",
            "ToolTip": "",
            "__expanded__": false,
            "Selected": "off"
        }
    ],
    "FilterGuid": "",
    "AgeRange": {
        "Min": 1,
        "Max": 18,
        "From": 3,
        "FromInit": 3,
        "To": 12,
        "ToInit": 12
    },
    "SelectedAges": [],
    "FilterCategories": {},
    "ResetFilter": "false"
},
"Request": ""
```

}

I expected that the error would not be thrown. There must be an issue with my C# classes, which I can not figure out. They can be found at: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ggsg552do3f21ca/AACv0wGZ18o0yG7heDnenOQ-a?dl=0
I'm trying to figure out where my C# classes are having the issue.
Thanks Abbott

Comment: I cannot find `BookGenieHandler` in the code. it seems important in this error. And could you reduce the code into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible?

Comment: chairman - I am trying to figure that out. This is inside the guts of a million line aspdonetstorefront web app and trying to unwire the various parts is painful. In paarallel, I am reducing the ajaxParams to several strings of json to see if I can bypass the issue3. I just love refactoring.

Comment: I just added BookGenieHandler to the fray ...

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the Asp.net WebMethods are quite persnickety when it comes to complex json. I got around the issue by creating a json object of json strings which I handled at both ends with converters. Here's the class ...

```
export class AjaxBookStringParams {
AgeCandidates: string = ""; // AllocationCandidates by age to-from server
BookToDelete:  string = ""; // Used to delete an allocated book
AllocatedBooks:  string = "";; // placeholder for to-from server - grid display
BookGenieParams: string = "";
Data: string = "";
ProductFilterParams:  string = "";
Request: string = "";
```

It's allowed me to concentrate on my own dumb/careless coding & typo errors ;-}

Thanks for everyone's help.
Abbott